# What does having disposition of 护短 means?

Tags: vocabulary

The context describe a character as having disposition of 护短. What does this means?

性格特点：护短！护短！护短！

I know that 护短 means to hide own's shortcoming. Does this describe a person who does not accept one's mistake? Shameless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

护短 is translated into to shield shortcomings or faults or to cover up one's mistakes.

This word is usually used to describe people who stop others from pointing out and criticizing their own weakness or their family, relatives or friends' weakness and mistakes ,and meanwhile defend themselves and their mistakes.

护短 is a very common and irrational phenomenon. Yes,it means people don't accept mistakes which are related to their family, relatives, friends and themselves. It's not a positive word.

Answer (score 2):

护短 is said 3 times, because it is important.

It conveys something like, "Don't judge me, my friends or my family; Never blame me or criticize me; If I make a mistake, you must ignore it. Got it?"

(nod)

"OK, now you are my friend."

Answer (score 1):

护短 is "side with a disputant(your child maybe) who is in the wrong".

It's not the disposition of 护短 for hiding one's own shortcomings. It's for one's own members, either within your org or family.

Most times, 护短 refers to protect your own member(s) (in your family or your organization) who is faulty in a dispute or fight. Let's say your kid quarreled with another kid of your neighbors'. You will speak for your own kid even though it is your kid's fault.